# ChangeList - построение дерева из нескольких моделей.

Tags: python, администрирование, django

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно построить дерево категорий таким образом что бы в нем содержались сами категории, и дочерние объекты которые относятся к этим категориям (связь один-ко-многому). Несколько дней путешествий по просторам Гугла ничего не дали, а свой велосипед изобретать не хотелось бы, потому что задача достаточно распространенная, и как мне кажется решение точно есть. Возможно кто либо знает как это сделать?

На всякий случай уточню, это нужно сделать в админ интерфейсе

Comment: сколько уровней вложенности? или их не фиксированное число?

Comment: У категорий не фиксированное число. У дочерних объектов нет вложенности.

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая ответ выше, смею предложить отредактировать шаблон change_list.html в FeinCMS (TreeEditor) конкретно для вашего аппа.

Ссылка на ознакомление: [Templates which may be overridden per app or model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model)

Answer (score 0):

Тогда вот такое поле используй:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ, но проблема не совсем в этом. Дело в том что я уже сделал так что бы категории отображались деревом, но к каждой категории через один-к-многому относятся характеристики представленные другой моделью, и требуется сделать так что бы и категории и характеристики из другой модели показывались в одном дереве. Для деревьев использую MPTT, для отображения TreeEditor из FeinCMS

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю точного задания, но могу предположить, что достаточно указать в шаблон отображения дерева переменную связывающую вашу категорию с полем связанной модели(и передать эту переменную в функцию views.py - которая отображает указанный шаблон) описание вывода категория-объект видела тут:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cr7j_rF8wyU

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?